# How to copy some buildscript classpath JARs but exclude others in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build-script

I have buildscript block that references many JARs:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies { classpath "com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13" }
    dependencies { classpath "com.eriwen:gradle-css-plugin:2.14.0" }
    dependencies { classpath "com.eriwen:gradle-js-plugin:2.14.1" }
    dependencies { classpath "com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:v20160208" }
    dependencies { classpath "org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+" }
}

task copyWarGradlePlugins(type: Copy) {
    destinationDir = file(project.buildDir.name + '/warGradlePlugins')

    from (buildscript.configurations.classpath)
}
```

I want to copy (to my WAR file) some of the referenced JARs (e.g. dependencies of gradle-css-plugin, gradle-js-plugin, closure-compiler) but not others (e.g. gretty, jmeter-gradle-plugin).

How do I exclude for example jmeter-gradle-plugin and all its dependencies?

UPDATE:
There are 150+ JARs. Excluding them by file name is not practical/maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    dependencies { classpath "com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13" }
    dependencies { classpath "com.eriwen:gradle-css-plugin:2.14.0" }
    dependencies { classpath "com.eriwen:gradle-js-plugin:2.14.1" }
    dependencies { classpath "com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:v20160208" }
    dependencies { classpath "org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+" }
}

task copyWarGradlePlugins(type: Copy) { copy ->
    destinationDir = file(project.buildDir.name + '/warGradlePlugins')

    copy.from(buildscript.configurations.classpath) { copySpec ->
        // exclusions are based on the file name as here you will be handed
        // DefaultFileVisitDetails type
        copySpec.exclude { it.name.startsWith 'gretty' }
        copySpec.exclude { it.name.startsWith 'closure-compiler' }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 150+ JARs. Excluding them by name is not practical or maintainable,